# How to Show name from firebase into flutter screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

```
  FirebaseUser loggedinuser;
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<void> currentUser()async
  {
    try
    {
      FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if(user != null)
      {
        setState(() {
          loggedinuser  = user;
        });
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentUser();
  }



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Logged in"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,vertical: 20),
        child: Text(loggedinuser.providerId)
```

Hi im new in FLutter and was working on a little project to practice
but whenever i try to show name of user i get an error saying that Text widget cant be null but im initializing the loggedinuser by using setState
i can see email but not the name on screen
Would appreciate the help

Comment: Since you are loading the user asyncronously, you will need a FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a FutureBuilder like the @nvoigt said. But you can also fix that changing this line `Text(loggedinuser.providerId)` to this:

```
Text(loggedinuser != null loggedinuser.providerId : "Loading / Not Logged in")
```

Using a FutureBuilder you would get something like this:

```
class LoadUser extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadUserState createState() => _LoadUserState();
}

class _LoadUserState extends State<LoadUser> {
  FirebaseUser loggedinuser;
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<FirebaseUser> currentUser() async {
    try {
      FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        return user;
      }
      return null;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("FirebaseUser"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
        child: FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
          future: currentUser(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
              case ConnectionState.active:
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                break;
              case ConnectionState.done:
                loggedinuser = snapshot.data;
                return Text(loggedinuser.providerId);
                break;
              default:
                return Text('Not logged in :(');
                break;
            }
          },
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you just a question
is Streambuilder the same as Futurebuilder??

Answer (score 0):

Your `currentUser()` function is asynchronous, it takes time to instantiate `loggedinuser`. So initially `loggedinuser` is `null`, thats why you are getting the error. To come up with the solution, wrap `Text` widget with `FutureBuilder`.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Logged in"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: currentUser(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              return Text(loggedInUser.providerId.toString());
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank You 
just wan to ask can i use Streambuilder instead of Futurebuilder??

Comment: If your `currentUser` function returns `Stream`, then you can use `StreamBuilder`. As it is returning `Future` , you can go with `FutureBuilder`. If my answer solves your problem, then accept the answer.